# Launching WebSharper client-server sitelet

Tags: .net, linux, f#, mono, websharper

I'm following WebSharper Sitelet tutorials, such as the minimal example [here](http://www.websharper.com/docs/sitelets), but I can't find documentation for launching a server-side process to host a sitelet that runs dynamic code on each request.

I can paste the example code into my editor and make basic changes to it, but it's unclear what I should do after I compile it. Do I have to hook it into some larger system?

I'm coding with Emacs on Linux, so I don't have any Visual Studio Just Does It <sup>(TM)</sup> magic to help me.